# Namespace std has no member bind1st?

Tags: c++, foreach, stl

I have a strange error trying to do use a for_each iteration over a vector of pointers
I want to call a method on each of these pointers

`objects_` is of type `vector<someClass*>`

```
for_each(objects_.begin(), objects_.end(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&someClass::someMethod), this));
```

But this doesn't even compile because :

```
error C2039: 'bind1st' : is not a member of 'std'
error C2039: 'mem_fun' : is not a member of 'std'
error C3861: 'bind1st': identifier not found
error C3861: 'mem_fun': identifier not found
```

However other stl algortihms and methods work properly.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: did you include `<functional>` ?

Comment: @PiotrS.  u_u I'm new to these things, that was the issue thanks. Add your answer, I'll upvote you for saving my time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::bind1st`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind1st) and [`std::mem_fn`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fn/) live in the [`<functional>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/) header, and will be visible to your translation unit as soon as you include that file:

```
#include <functional>
```

Also, please note that `std::bind1st` is **deprecated**, and you should be using lambda expressions or a more versatile [`std::bind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind).

Comment: At time of writing (2020), compiling with a C++-17 standard under clang 9, uses of bind1st etc have to be rewritten as it is not just deprecated, but removed.

Comment: Won't recommend, but one can force clang to use deprecated stuff with: `-D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_FEATURES`